# How to take a space separated character sequence as input in java without knowing number of characters input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I wish to read a space-separated character sequence in java but the number of characters to be input is not known. For example, this is the input `12 34 e 2 a 9 d`

How do I store each of these in a list?

I tried using:

```
while(scan.hasNext())
    list.add(scan.next().charAt(0)); // list is an ArrayList<Character>
```

Can someone tell me why this doesn't work? (I am having a hard time understanding what method `hasNext()` really does.

Comment: Can you include an example of the type of sequence being inputted along with you desired functionality?

Comment: The number of characters *is* known. What are you talking about? It is given by `String.length()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the words, you can use `String.trim().split(" ")`. This will remove leading and trailing whitespaces, and return an array of words that were seperated by whitespaces.

You can also use `Scanner sc = new Scanner(<your file>).useDelimiter(" ");` to configure your scanner to split the text into tokens using the spaces as breaks.

`Scanner.hasNext()` returns a boolean value depending on whether there is a next token or not.

`String.charAt(0)` returns the first character of the string. If you want to read every letter, you'll have to loop through each word using `String.charAt(<loop variable>)`

Comment: I would add a call to [`strip`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#strip()) as well as `trim`. Uses the Unicode definition of white space.

Comment: If this is what you need, accept it by clicking the check icon next to it.

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks for the input. I didn't think OP would need it since the question seems quite basic.